# Flashlight app getting closed in background

Tags: android, flashlight

I am developing a flashlight app and the thing is that the app is working as expected, but not when "home" or "back" key is pressed. i want my app to keep the torch light on even when the user presses "Home" key so that user can do other works while torch is on. On back key, the flash turning off is fine. Here is my code. Please help me with it, thanx a lot to all.

```
public class LightsOn extends Activity implements OnKeyListener
{
    ImageView button;
    Boolean flashon=true;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters myparas;
    private Camera mycamera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_light);

        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        button=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.power);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offswitch);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flashon)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LightsOn.this, "Flashlight off..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onswitch);
                    if (mycamera == null || myparas == null) 
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
                        myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
                        mycamera.stopPreview();
                        flashon=false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LightsOn.this, "Flashlight on..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offswitch);
                    if (mycamera == null || myparas == null) 
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
                        myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
                        mycamera.startPreview();
                        flashon=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getCamera() 
    {
        if (mycamera == null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                mycamera = Camera.open();
                myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
            } 
            catch (RuntimeException e)
            {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (!hasFlash)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Sorry your device doesnt support flash.");
            dialog.setMessage("Press 'OKAY' to exit..");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Okay.. :( :(", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    finish();
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("More Apps by ****", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LightsOn.this, "Account Coming Soon..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNeutralButton("See website for more", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LightsOn.this, "Website to be Launched Soon..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            });
        dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // on pause turn off the flash
        myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
        myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
        mycamera.stopPreview();
        flashon=false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    

        if(hasFlash)
        myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
        myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
        mycamera.startPreview();
        flashon=true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // on stop release the camera
        if (mycamera != null)
        {
            mycamera.release();
            mycamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // on starting the app get the camera params
        getCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m)
    {
        MenuInflater inf=getMenuInflater(); 
        inf.inflate(R.menu.menu,m);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `onPause()` you turning flash mode off, do it on only `onBackPressed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution.

What you should do is, write all the code like following in `onBackPressed`. I merge two methods code in one method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
    myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
    mycamera.stopPreview();
    flashon = false;

    if (mycamera != null) {
        mycamera.release();
        mycamera = null;
    }
    Log.d("Camera","Back Pressed");
}
```

And remove all the code from `onStop()` and `onPause()` method. Because when you press `Home` key, it calls first `onPause()` and then `onStop()`. I implement your code and worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change you `onPause()` to this and also `onStop()` if you need to

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

and add this

```
@Override
protected void onBackPressed() { 
    super.onBackPressed();
    // on back turn off the flash
    myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
    myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
    mycamera.stopPreview();
    flashon=false;
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html here is activity cycle, and thats enough ;)

Comment: But either answer is not good way implementing it, you should do it in a service, because OS may kill activity anytime.

Comment: Thats also a point. But if flash light is on in service or any other, it will obviously drain battery. Its the main disadvantage :0 .

Comment: But user needs flash to be on, Service can be stopped once user turns off flash :)

Comment: I think you have made one mistake. He has written release in `onStop`. Don't you think when `Home` key is pressed, `onStop` will be called?

Comment: Ya, that may gets called too . And i have mentioned it in answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Got it,
The answer is to simply superimpose onPause() method and then, turn off the flash in the onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
}
```

this is onBackPressed()

```
@Override
protected void onBackPressed() { 
super.onBackPressed();

myparas = mycamera.getParameters();
myparas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
mycamera.setParameters(myparas);
mycamera.stopPreview();
flashon=false;
}
```

Although now I can see that the answers provided above are also suggesting same as wel.. So its a well proven answer now I guess. @akshat should go for it..

Comment: your answer is not different then `SIGSEGV`'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I Modified the code set !

It worked for me ! Thanks

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
  //  turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // on resume turn on the flash
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.stopPreview();
    isFlashOn = false;

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    Log.d("Camera","Back Pressed");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
 //   if (camera != null) {
 //       camera.release();
  //      camera = null;
   // }
}
```